# Implementing incremental search in emacs

Tags: search, emacs, elisp

I would like to improve emacs-eclim and add incremental search through java types in the currently edited project (Shift-Ctrl-H in Eclipse).

I can call eclim-java-find variants to get the results in an *eclim: find buffer.

But here comes my question:

How does one implement a behaviour that lets the user to type into a minibuffer (with a prompt) and calls some other function on each minibuffer change (new/deleted character) with the current minibuffer content as an argument or some other way of accessing the current search string.

Comment: I don't know about emacs-eclim, but are you talking about tab-completion of strings? If you have access to, or can generate, a string of the possible java types you want to find, you can use functions like `completing-read`. This allows you to interactively narrow down choices in the minibuffer given a list of target strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a function to `post-command-hook`, for example. which is called after every command (typing a character is also a command: `self-insert-command`). Your function can then check the minibuffer contents with the function `minibuffer-contents`.

Just don't forget to remove your function from `post-command-hook` when your search command is finished. You can use `minibuffer-setup-hook` and `minibuffer-exit-hook` to control attaching your function.

Just don't forget to remove your attaching function from `minibuffer-setup-hook`/`minibuffer-exit-hook` either when the search command is finished. :)